# Sql query producing "array to string conversion error"

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am using an array in an sql statement, and it is producing an error
**Array to string conversion in "name of file and line number."**
  This is my code.

```
$temp=array(2,3,4,9);
    for($i=4; $i>=0; $i--) {

    $query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_id IN ('$temp')");
    if ($query1) {
        echo '<br> hello'.$i;
    }
}
```

I've also tried this

```
 $query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_id IN ('$temp[$i]')");
```

Instead of

```
 $query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_id IN ('$temp')");
```

in above code.

Comment: This is your start point `('$temp')`

Comment: This is because `$temp` is an array not an string.

Comment: @Nima how to solve it then

Comment: So you need foreach array value needed to be inserted WHERE u_id = matching array id?

Comment: The query shouldn't be in a loop. If you need to iterate the results of the query, loop through the results. But as written, you'll just run `SELECT .... WHERE u_id IN (2,3,4,9) 4 times. I'm not sure that's what you want to do. Also, you'll need to convert that array to a comma delimited string to put in ti the IN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get `SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_id IN (2,3,4,9)`, then cast your array into coma-separated string `implode(',', $temp)`

Adjust your code like:

```
$tmp = [2, 3, 4, 9];
$usersStr = implode(',', $tmp);
...
$query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_id IN ($usersStr)");
```

Comment: You should show the actual php code, as im sure the op is getting the string interpolation syntax wrong

Answer (score 1):

You run the query in a loop. And you transmit the array, but must be string.

```
$temp=array(2,3,4,9);

// Convert to string
$str = implode(',', $temp);

for($i=4;$i>=0;$i--){

 $query1=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_id IN (".$str.")");

 if($query1->num_rows){
    echo '<br> hello'.$i;
 }
}
```